# automatic events in kivy & python

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I'm trying to work out how to put a clock on a kivy app but am having difficulty.

I can make it work via a button..  (ie. if I click the button, it'll update the clock time on the label)  but I can't seem to make it work automatically updating each second.

Any help greatly appreciated!

The event line commented out, I can make work with just a simple file with a print command but not in the context of changing the text of a label.  It just says "missing 1 argument"

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import time
from kivy.clock import Clock


class test(BoxLayout):
    def showClock(self,dt):
         timey = (time.strftime("%H"+":"+"%M"+":"+"%S")),dt
         self.ids.labelID.text = (timey[0])
    event = Clock.schedule_interval(showClock, 1)




class question(App):
    def build(self):       
        return test()

if __name__ =="__main__":
    question().run()
```

KV file:

```
<test>:
    id:test
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            id: labelID
            text:"label"
        Button:
            id: buttonID
            text:"button"
            on_release:test.showClock(1)
```

EDIT:

The error reads:

```
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\clock.py", line 406, in tick
ret = callback(self._dt)
TypeError: showClock() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dt'
```

EDIT2:

After a lot of experimenting and looking at other people's code online, I have managed to get it to work..   although I'm not sure why or how..  any explanation would be greatly appreciated to help my understanding...

The code that works is:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import time
from kivy.clock import Clock


class test(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(test, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.showClock, 1)

    def showClock(self, dt):
         timey = (time.strftime("%H"+":"+"%M"+":"+"%S")),dt
         self.ids.labelID.text = (timey[0])



class question(App):
    def build(self):       
        return test()

if __name__ =="__main__":
    question().run()
```

Comment: always put in question full error message (Traceback).

Comment: which element has problem with `"missing 1 argument"` - check in documentation how many arguments it expects.

Comment: The error reads:      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\clock.py", line 406, in tick
     ret = callback(self._dt)
 TypeError: showClock() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dt'
>>>

Comment: shouldn't be `self.showClock` in `schedule_interval(self.showClock, 1)` ?

Comment: When I do that, it says:       event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.showClock, 1)
 NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: do you have `showClock(self, dt)` and other `showClock()` function ?

Comment: I only have the code above..  I copy and pasted it in its entirety..   (or have I misunderstood your question?)

Answer (score 0):

Your function showClock expects the argument dt. You can use "partial" to pass that argument. It is explained in the docs: https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html
Hope this helps.

Comment: I've been experimenting with partial, but can't seem to work it out..   do I want to pass that argument?  Don't I need the dt to determine when it will update?  The problem I can't get my head around is the use of "self".  Without the self I can print the clock to the command line no problem.   But without self I can't update the label text...    not sure how to get around that

Comment: Because the function will always reference "self", if you leave it out, you will just call the same instance thats being passed "dt" instead of "self". That is valid syntax but common use is to call this argument self... What exactly does not work using partial?

Comment: It says:  self.ids.labelID.text = (timey[0])
 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ids'

It prints to the console now though automatically.. so getting closer!   

I have constructed it like this:

    def showClock(self, dt, *largs):
         timey = (time.strftime("%H"+":"+"%M"+":"+"%S")),dt
         print(timey[0])
         self.ids.labelID.text = (timey[0])
    event = Clock.schedule_interval(partial(showClock,"my self","my key"),1)

Comment: That is because you passed two strings as arguments ("my self" and "my key"). This is the place where you should pass your functions variables (shouldnt dt be an int?). A string does not have the attribute ids. No matter if you call it "my self" or any different.

Comment: Could you accept my answer if you got it to work? Thanks!